# Retrieving list of NFT assets using web3 python module

Tags: python, ethereum, nft, web3py

I am new to web3 and am trying to use the web3 python package to crawl the ethereum blockchain for all NFT assets from a particular marketplace e.g Opensea. How do I go about this and are there any links to tutorials on this kind of task apart from the web3 documentation?

Comment: Your question needs to be a bit more precise with some code preferably. What have you coded do you have so far?

Comment: Yes can you clarify further on this? Also NFT are not attached to any particular marketplace, they can be traded in any marketplace and not stuck in just one of them to be fetched. Most likely what are you looking for are NFT assets that are traded on certain platform like OpenSea?